# Scrollview inside another view does not works in react native

Tags: react-native

```
render() {
    return (


<View style ={styles.container}>    
    {/*for header*/}
     <View style = {{flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:'space-between',alignItems: 'center',width:'100%',height:'09%',backgroundColor: '#009AFF'}}>

                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() =>this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
                             <Image style={{width: 25, height: 25,margin:10}}  source={require('../assets/clinic/left-arrow.png')} />
                 </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

                 <View>
                  <Text style={{fontSize: 21,fontWeight: 'bold', color: "white",paddingRight:25}}>Dummy</Text>
                 </View>

                <View>
                </View>

     </View>

     {/*for main content*/}

     <ScrollView style={{width:'100%',height:'90%'}}  contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }} nestedScrollEnabled={true}> 
     <View>

    <View style = {{width:'100%',height:'45%',backgroundColor: '#009AFF',justifyContent:'center',alignItems: 'center'}}>
    <Text style={{fontSize: 18,fontWeight: 'bold', color: "white",paddingRight:25}}>John Alison</Text>
     </View>

     <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.submitButton}>
                <Text style={styles.submitText}>Update</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
     <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.submitButton}>
                <Text style={styles.submitText}>Update</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
     <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.submitButton}>
                <Text style={styles.submitText}>Update</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

     </View>
     </ScrollView>

</View>

)
}
```

Above code i have implemented in react native for learning purposes.But in above code ScrollView does not works,means it does not scrolls,why? i have tried many possible ways like setting flex and flexGrow equal to 1,enabling nested scrolling but it does not works.What is wrong with my code

Comment: try to remove the `style={{width:'100%',height:'90%'}} ` from your `ScrollView`.

Comment: i tries but it does not works!

Comment: I just tried your code and it works. On which platform are you testing it?

Comment: on android platform

Comment: using flex:1 on all child makes scrolling but it shrinks the size of the view below header which has height of 45%